# In Unity 3D, how do you get the bounds of an object as size of screen is scaled?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

So I'm trying to attach an object to the mouse, but in the upper left corner. In the past I've done things like this (where the origin of the object is in the center):

`thing.x = mouseX - thing.width/2;
 thing.y = mouseY - thing.height/2;`

I've effectively done the same in Unity with a sprite, however whenever I scale the Game in Unity (dragging to resize the game panel, or with a build selecting a lower resolution), r.bounds.size will not change when placed in Update.

Answer (score 0):

If your game object is a menu item (you wrote it is a Panel), then you have a `RectTransform` component attached to the object. You can access the dynamic size with this :

```
Vector2 windowSize = YourObject.rectTransform.sizeDelta;
```